# Find a point on a circle given a point and height

Tags: trigonometry, circles

[Point on a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sykzd.png)

[image]

Given :
A point on a circle (point and angle), 
radius of the circle ,
height (Orthogonal to horizon )
I would like to find
A point on a circle
or , and
The angle between the given point (x,y) and the new point (?,?)

Thanks !

Comment: The definition of "height" (h) is pretty unclear: is that the height over the *horizontal* diameter of the circle or what?

Comment: No , sorry for being unclear , maybe the use of the term height here is wrong,  it is a given number from point x,y on a line that is orthogonal to the circle horizon .

Comment: Can you give a line equation $\vec{p}(t) = \vec{x} + t\vec{a}$ of that line orthogonal to the circle horizon? The intermediate point unter $(x,y)$ looks like $(x, y-h)$ to me.

Comment: @user Thank you, I understand now: h is the height on the verti8cal axis from the wanted point ?? to the given point (x,y)

Comment: Yes , @Joanpemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a wild guess, given that that intermediary point is just $(x, y-h)$.

Given $\alpha$ and $r$, calculate $(x,y) = (r \cos(\alpha), r\sin(\alpha))$ (plus an offest $\vec{p_0}$ if the circle is not at $(0,0)$.

Then, subtract $h$ from the y-coordinate, which should give you the point $(x,y') = (x, y-h)$:

[image]

If the new $y'$ coordinate is fixed then calculate the correct $x'$ coordinate by solving the circle equation in cartesian coordinates
$$x'^2 + y'^2 = r^2$$ 
with $y', r$ fixed and take the $x'$ that has the same sign as $x$. 
You will receive $(?,?)$ = $(x',y')$.

If you have the new point you can calculate the angle between the points $(x,y)$ and $(x', y')$ as

$$\alpha' = \text{atan2}\left(y'-y, x'-x\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your angle $\alpha$ determines your point $(x,y)=(r\sin \alpha,r\cos \alpha)$ and immediately you obtain $$(?,?)=(r\sin \alpha,r\cos \alpha-h)$$